# Intuit OpenID Connect, Authorization code returned by the server not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, omniauth, quickbooks-online

I'm trying to implement OpenId Connect for QuickBooks, as they are deprecating in 2019 OAuth1.

In the documentation [here](https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/develop/authentication-and-authorization/openid-connect#step-3-intuit-prompts-user-for-consent), I have first to prepare an authorization request to redirect the user to the Intuit OAUth 2.0 server.

To handle all the process, I use the omniauth strategy gem *omniauth-quickbooks-oauth2*. Here is the omniauth setup:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  # Open ID Connect
  provider(
    :quickbooks_oauth2,
    ENV['INTUIT_CLIENT_ID'],
    ENV['INTUIT_CLIENT_SECRET'],
    scope: 'com.intuit.quickbooks.accounting openid profile email phone address',
    sandbox: Rails.env.development?,
  )
end
```

It generates the following request:

```
https://appcenter.intuit.com/connect/oauth2?client_id=MYCLIENTID&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fauth%2Fquickbooks_oauth2%2Fcallback&response_type=code&scope=com.intuit.quickbooks.accounting+openid+profile+email+phone+address&state=71f636c1097f8d5bf07a66df5ca64ec43800ea90f6bcedca
```

Once the user grants the access, Intuit redirect to my redirect URL, and after the user authentification, I get the Authorization code from the params to request the tokens.

For this I use the Gem *oauth2*

```
oauth_params = {
      :site => "https://appcenter.intuit.com/connect/oauth2",
      :authorize_url => "https://appcenter.intuit.com/connect/oauth2",
      :token_url => "https://oauth.platform.intuit.com/oauth2/v1/tokens/bearer"
    }
client = OAuth2::Client.new(ENV['INTUIT_CLIENT_ID'], ENV['INTUIT_CLIENT_SECRET'], oauth_params)

client.auth_code.get_token(authorization_code,
                                :redirect_uri => 'http://localhost:3000/auth/quickbooks_oauth2/callback',
                                :grant_type => "authorization_code")
```

I then obtain an error message:

```
OAuth2::Error: invalid_grant:
{"error":"invalid_grant"}
```

I checked my call back uri are the same on the Intuit developer portal:

```
http://localhost:3000/auth/quickbooks_oauth2/callback
```

When I try my code to obtain the tokens from the authorization code I obtained from the Intuit OAUth2 Playground, it works!
Which make me believe the issue may be coming from the implementation of Omniauth, But I'm stucked!

Comment: Looks like this code works in sandbox, but not all the time. Is anyone aware of instability with the OAuth2 Intuit's API?